# Drools rule - null check and accumulate condition

Tags: java, drools

I'm currently doing some fix on a java batch which run a set of `Drools` (yeuch!) rules.

The rule I have to fix is this:

```
rule "Insert a too old condition"
        salience -1
    when
        $person : Person()
        $tooOldInstant : DateTime() from now.minusDays(10)
        DateTime( this < $tooOldInstant ) from accumulate (
            LastData( $date : lastDate ) from $person.personLastDatas,
            maxValue($date)
        )
    then
        insert(new Condition("submitTooOldCondition"));
end
```

where for simplification `Person` is a simple bean with a *personLastDatas* `Set<LastData>` AND `LastData` has a `org.joda.time.DateTime` *lastDate* property.

Question: How do I insert a new condition where if `$person.personLastDatas` is null the rule apply?

Something like:

```
rule "Insert a too old condition modified"
        salience -1
    when
        $person : Person()
        $tooOldInstant : DateTime() from now.minusDays(10)
        $maxLastDate : DateTime() from accumulate (
            LastData( $date : lastDate ) from $person.personLastDatas,
            maxValue($date)
        )
        ($maxLastDate == null || $maxLastDate < $tooOldInstant)
    then
        insert(new Condition("submitTooOldCondition"));
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have two rules, one for the null condition and one for the one that compares the dates.

Here is the null condition rule; it verifies that the Person exists but that it has no `personLastDatas` property:

```
rule "Insert a too old condition modified - null case"
salience -1
when
  $person: Person( personLastDatas == null )
then
  insert(new Condition("submitTooOldCondition"));
end
```

Your existing rule is sufficient for the date comparison check.

In general, if you find yourself trying to do complex if-else logic on either side of the rule, it's a good indication that you should have two rules. Since these two rules cannot *both* be true, you'll only have one condition of this type inserted.

That being said, if you're using a modern version of drools, you can use conditional and namespaced consequences. The [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/7.37.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/index.html#drl-rules-THEN-advanced-con_drl-rules) covers this in detail (I've linked 7.37.0.Final; most of the recent 7.30+ versions have this functionality.) Below is an example of what your rule might look like:

```
rule "Insert a too old condition"
salience -1
when
  $person : Person( $lastDatas: personLastDatas )
  if ( $lastDatas == null ) break[noData]
  $tooOldInstant : DateTime() from now.minusDays(10)
  DateTime( this < $tooOldInstant ) from accumulate (
            LastData( $date : lastDate ) from $person.personLastDatas,
            maxValue($date)
  )
then
  insert(new Condition("submitTooOldCondition"));
then[noData]
  // any special logic for the null case goes here
  insert(new Condition("submitTooOldCondition"));
end
```

(This is pseudo-code; I don't have a drools project on this computer but it should be similar.)

Basically this syntax, though harder to read, will allow you to handle these sorts of repetitive/partial shared case rules. They're usually recommended for cases where you have two rules, where one extends the other, so a subset of the common conditions can trigger one consequence, while the full set of the conditions can trigger another consequence. That's not quite what you have here, but the functionality can be bastardized for your use case.

The `break` keyword tells the engine to stop evaluating the left hand side once the condition is met; there's also a `do` keyword which allows for continued evaluation.

Comment: Nice answer, tomorrow I'm gonna try it. Just as a quick integration, is there a way to test is the Set<LastData> is null OR empty? Something like Person( personLastDatas == null || personLastDatas.isEmpty())

Comment: Yes you can do "or'd" conditions like that in `Person( ... )`

Comment: Seems to work! Thank you very much, I hope I don't have to touch any Drools related stuff for a long time. For a moment I've thought about rewriting all this stuff in plain java.

Comment: Drools is actually surprisingly a lot faster than Java for a lot of things. If you need to make lots of decisions, it's the better of the two, especially if there are lots of rules. It just takes a bit of time to wrap your mind around the syntax and the workflow.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1**

```
rule "Insert a too old condition"
        salience -1
    when
        Person(personLastDatas == null)
        or
        $person : Person()
        and $tooOldInstant : DateTime() from now.minusDays(10)
        and DateTime( this < $tooOldInstant ) from accumulate (
            LastData( $date : lastDate ) from $person.personLastDatas,
            maxValue($date)
        )
    then
        System.out.println("submitTooOldCondition");
end
```

**Option 2**

Make your aggregate function work the way you need. *From the business you expressed in the rule, null DateTime should be treated as a lowest possible value.* If this is true for all other rules, you can encapsulate this logic in your `maxValue` function.

```
public Object getResult(HashSet<DateTime> context) throws Exception {
    return context.isEmpty() ? new DateTime(0) /*null*/ : context.iterator().next();
}
```

With the logic above your original rule will work as expected without any modification.

---

test

```
@DroolsSession(resources = "classpath:/test.drl")
public class PlaygroundTest {

    @Rule
    public DroolsAssert drools = new DroolsAssert();

    @Test
    @TestRules(expectedCount = { "2", "Insert a too old condition" })
    public void testIt() {
        drools.setGlobal("now", now());
        drools.insertAndFire(new Person(newHashSet(new LastData(now().minusDays(100)), new LastData(now().minusDays(5)))));
        drools.insertAndFire(new Person(newHashSet(new LastData(now().minusDays(100)), new LastData(now().minusDays(15)))));
        drools.insertAndFire(new Person(null));
    }
}
```

test output

```
00:00:00 --> inserted: Person[personLastDatas=[org.droolsassert.LastData@25243bc1, org.droolsassert.LastData@1e287667]]
00:00:00 --> fireAllRules
00:00:00 --> inserted: Person[personLastDatas=[org.droolsassert.LastData@76f10035, org.droolsassert.LastData@5ab9b447]]
00:00:00 --> fireAllRules
00:00:00 <-- 'Insert a too old condition' has been activated by the tuple [Person, DateTime, DateTime]
submitTooOldCondition
00:00:00 --> inserted: Person[personLastDatas=<null>]
00:00:00 --> fireAllRules
00:00:00 <-- 'Insert a too old condition' has been activated by the tuple [Person]
submitTooOldCondition
```

function source

```
public class MaxValueAccumalateFunction implements AccumulateFunction<HashSet<DateTime>> {

    @Override
    public void writeExternal(ObjectOutput out) throws IOException {
    }

    @Override
    public void readExternal(ObjectInput in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    }

    @Override
    public HashSet<DateTime> createContext() {
        return new HashSet<>();
    }

    @Override
    public void init(HashSet<DateTime> context) throws Exception {
    }

    @Override
    public void accumulate(HashSet<DateTime> context, Object value) {
        if (context.isEmpty() || context.iterator().next().isBefore((DateTime) value)) {
            context.clear();
            context.add((DateTime) value);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void reverse(HashSet<DateTime> context, Object value) throws Exception {
    }

    @Override
    public Object getResult(HashSet<DateTime> context) throws Exception {
        return context.isEmpty() ? new DateTime(0) /*null*/ : context.iterator().next();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supportsReverse() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getResultType() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

rule source

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import accumulate org.droolsassert.MaxValueAccumalateFunction maxValue;

global DateTime now;

rule "Insert a too old condition"
        salience -1
    when
        Person(personLastDatas == null)
        or
        $person : Person()
        and $tooOldInstant : DateTime() from now.minusDays(10)
        and DateTime( this < $tooOldInstant ) from accumulate (
            LastData( $date : lastDate ) from $person.personLastDatas,
            maxValue($date)
        )
    then
        System.out.println("submitTooOldCondition");
end
```